# Fancybox jQuery / Close box when page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

Inside a fancybox, I want to execute some PHP, then make the box closed automatically.

Here's what's in the FAQ

> 5. How can I close FancyBox from other element? ?
>      Just call $.fancybox.close() on your onClick event

Where to put this in my page ?

This is what I made (not working) :

```
    <?php   ... (my php)      ?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">
</head>

  <body onload="$.fancybox.close();">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.fizzyexpress.pro/admin/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.fizzyexpress.pro/admin/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>  

</body>
```

Sorry, I'm newbie ...
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just close it when page is loaded, you can use `document.ready()` like below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

But if you need to run a `PHP` script, and then close fancybox, you must make an `AJAX` call, then call `$fancybox.close()` into `success`. See [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)